# Rings with bounded index of nilpotency are Dedekind-Finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

Recently in an article by A. A. Klein I have seen this result:

> A ring $R$ with bounded index of nilpotence is Dedekind-Finite.

Can anyone help me prove this result?

Answer (score 1):

We adapt the argument given in [this blogpost](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/rings-with-only-finitely-many-nilpotent-elements-are-dedekind-finite/), where it is shown that if a ring $R$ has finitely many nilpotent elements, then it is Dedekind finite.

Suppose that $R$ is not Dedekind finite; let $a,b \in R$ be such that $ab = 1$ but $ba \neq 1$. Consider the elements $e_{i,j} = b^{i-1} a^{j-1} - b^i a^j$ for integers $i,j \geqslant 1$. It is not hard to show that $$e_{i,j} e_{k,l} = \delta_{j,k} e_{i,l}$$ where $\delta_{j,k} = 1$ if $j = k$ and is zero otherwise (this is done explicitly in the blogpost mentioned above). Using this formula and an induction, it is easy to check that $$e_{1,2} + e_{2,3} + \cdots + e_{n-1, n}$$ is nilpotent of index $n$, and therefore $R$ does not have bounded index of nilpotency.